# When I click on + operator and immediately I want to click on * that's will be change into * but it's not happening

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

[that's the screshot of my image where I stuck. If you want to see my code you can check into my previous question I put my all code there .]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FUhRz9C-7bge9CWjCYlIFZ_xIfF1XPU9/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: That's in my previous question you can check

Comment: Where is the question

Comment: U can check my profile there you got my code

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can check in a condition for the last character, if it was previously an operator, then remove the last character (the last operator) to update the string with new operator.
e.g.

```
def btnclick(num):
    global start
    if (start[-1]=='+'  or start[-1]=='-' or start[-1]=='*' or start[-1]=='/') and (num=='+' or num=='-' or num=='*' or num=='/'):
        start=start[:-1]    
    start=start+str(num)
    text.set(start)
```